# Using local area network for gRPC Connection

Tags: c#, grpc

Is it possible to use a gRPC Service running on a server in a local area network provided by a wifi router with no internet access?
Server and Client are both connected to the local wifi.
How must I configure the connection to make things work?

Comment: gRPC usually uses HTTP/2 with TLS over TCP; none of those things require internet access so it should work fine; did you try it? What happened? Note that TLS can be bypassed if absolutely required (although it is not usually recommended). Use on local connections is pretty common.

Comment: (I also have an experimental spike of an alternative gRPC transport that bypasses HTTP/2, for use on raw sockets, named pipes, etc; but emphasis: experimental)

Comment: I get a grpc exception, when I try it
Grpc.Core.RPCException: Status(StatusCode="Internal", Detail="Object reference not set to an instance of an object.", DebugException="Grpc.Core.Internal.CoreErrorDetailException: {"created":"@1654159763.890796772","description":"Error received from peer ipv4:192.168.0.166:30051","file":"/var/local/git/grpc/src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":904,"grpc_message":"Object reference not set to an instance of an object.","grpc_status":13}")

Comment: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` you have a simple Null Reference Excption refer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142 seems unrelated to gRpc, just something wrong with the endpoint you are calling - FYI use @[username] to notify users about your messages